# Possibly change retract flag button to red or another color

Tags: feature-request, design, flags

Today on Stack Overflow, I flagged an answer for NAA and left a comment. The user then edited his answer to fix it, so I wanted to retract the flag. This was my first time ever retracting a flag, so I had no idea where it was. I even checked the flagging dialog for it. While this is where I found it, the button was blue. I guess my brain just assumed it was the same button that was used to post a flag so I missed it.

So I guess my suggestion is to possibly change the color of the retract button to a more brighter color like red, or something different than blue. Although red brings forth the issue of associating a more negative connotation of retracting a flag, so I am unsure.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it'd make more sense to move the button so that it's next to the "This is the flag you currently have raised" text, rather than changing the color.

Comment: @Catija yeah I thought about that too, would be much easier to see and make sense

Comment: Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to discover things ... ;)

Comment: @rene yes apparently, your eyes for example. I don't think I would have ever found it.